# need to merge date and time in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have below php code to insert date and time in php.

```
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="#999999" scope="row"><div align="center" class="style13">
      <div align="left">Event End Time </div>
    </div></th>
    <td width="265"><input name="edate" type="date" id="from_date">
    <input name="etime" type="time" id="from_time"></td>

    </tr>
```

i want to insert this date and time value in one column in mysql database.
to insert data i am writing below code.

```
$event_etime = $_POST['edate'];
```

here only date field is inserting. can anyone help me how can i merge date and time both in this column.

Comment: Perhaps `$event_etime = $_POST['edate'].' '.$_POST['from_time'];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate two values like

```
$event_etime = $_POST['edate'].' '.$_POST['etime'];
```

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
$event_etime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($_POST['edate'].' '.$_POST['etime']));
```

and your table field type must be `datetime`